# How to have an old version of Ruby on Cloud9

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide

I have a source code that I want to test on Cloud9 hosting (I have premium account). However, the problem is that the source code is bade on Ruby 1.8, mysql-essential-5.0 and other old libraries.

How can I create a plain VM on cloud9 and install ruby and other version by myself ? So far all i see that all vms are pre-configured with ruby 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud9 IDE comes with rvm preinstalled, so this is nice. Otherwise, all VM are pre-configured with Ruby 2.1.5 (not 4) and Rails 4.1.6

The only thing you have to do in your console is :

```
# Check your actual Ruby version
ruby -v
# ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux] 

# Install ruby 1.8 (if it's not already done)
rvm install ruby-1.8

# Switch ruby version
rvm use 1.8
```

---

For MySQL I would first do an uninstallation of your current version of mysql with `sudo apt-get uninstall mysql*` and then install it from source. You can [check this link](http://geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/installation/downloading_compiling_and_installing_mysql_server_from_source_code.php) for more info.

Comment: What about MySQL ? I have to use version 5.0